# H2 DB computed columns - reference to table field

Tags: sql, h2

I want to make computed column based on calculation with data from another table.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD avg_price DOUBLE AS (SELECT AVG(price)
                   FROM goods
                   WHERE id = ?);
```

`?` - should be `table1.id` for computed row

- How can I reference to column in `table1`?
- How to update value for id when to `goods` table added or removed data for this id

Edited: sorry, not Postgres - H2

Comment: In order to do this, you would need to use a user-defined function.

Comment: Postgres appears to [not support computed columns](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200309291034.22178.josh%40agliodbs.com).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_table1
AS
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1,
LATERAL (SELECT AVG(price) AS avg_price
         FROM goods g
         WHERE g.id = t1.id) v1;
```

Also storing price as `DOUBLE`  is not best idea. Better use `DECIMAL`. From [Floating-Point Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html)

> If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead.